# Okteto scaling deployment back to 1 replica

Tags: okteto

I am using Okteto to develop in my k8s cluster (not to deploy or build).
When my deployment has 2 replicas, Okteto scales it back to 1.
Is there any way to prevent this (i.e. have Okteto map my code changes into the 2 pods and not scale it back to 1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, okteto is only able to synchronize changes with one pod, so it automatically 'forces' 1 replica for your dev environment.

This is a good idea though, could you open a [feature request](https://github.com/okteto/okteto/issues/new?assignees=&labels=triage&template=feature_request.md&title=) in our repo? The more you can talk about your scenario there, the easier will be for us to prioritize it.